# "Add semicolon and goto new line" hotkey

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android programing. I use Android Studio (v0.8.9).
Here is problem a tackled with:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  adds a semicolon and moves the caret to the end of the line,
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not a add semicolon and moves the caret to a new line.
Question is how to make InteliJ IDEA add semicolon to the end of current line and move caret to the new line by pressing, say, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add semicolon after method call when inside parameter list in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332227/how-to-add-semicolon-after-method-call-when-inside-parameter-list-in-intellij-id)

Comment: Not quite. They recommend use ctrl+shift+Enter - which adds semicolon BUT lives caret at the end of the line. I need add caret and goto new line, as if you pressed consequently ctrl+shift+Enter and then Enter.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
twice should do the job. You can record a keyboard macro that does it, and assign a custom shortcut to it.

Comment: Thank you Peter. This should work but it's kind of... ugly. There should the way to do it by means of android studio, without any macro recorders, right?

Comment: There's currently no such action built into IntelliJ or Android Studio. There's a request for changing Complete Statement (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7065) but it's not very likely to be implemented because it breaks user habits.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best if there's just a setting for it? Like an opt-in in the Preferences or something.

Comment: That might be possible, especially if it becomes clear there's more benefit than harm from complicating the UI and the behavior.

Comment: This works great. And it could not only add semicolon, but also add curly bracket based on context.

Comment: Recording a macro is super easy. You press Ctrl+Shift+Enter twice, name it, then select it from the Keymap.

Comment: `cmd + shift + enter` on mac

Comment: True life saver. Didn't know that. Now I can get rid of my stupid macro.

Answer (score 2):

It's 2020 now and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut now works as expected in Android Studio (tested 4.1.1). MacOS version should have a different modifier, but should be almostly same.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the IDE to add semicolon If you have code completion enabled you can press tab on your code snippet, then press shift+enter to go to a new line.

For example:
 1. type sout and press tab.
 2. the editor fills in `System.out.println($CursorHere);`
 3. type "foobar" where the cursor appears.
 4. press shift enter and you'll be taken to a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise your shortcuts in preferences - > Keymap

[image: Set custom shortcut]

Edit or add new shorts cut is very easy from here.